# Set soft keyboard default to numeric on Android browser app using jQueryMobile

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, numeric

I want to be able to open the Android softkeyboard using Javascript in numeric mode.

There are numerous posts out there about how to open the softkeyboard and about how to set its data type to numeric, but in my case there are some circumstances that prevent me from combining these solutions.

Currently, if the user manually taps the input field, the numeric soft keyboard appears correctly.
I've also figured out how to use the java method .addJavascriptInterface() to create a Javascript function that opens and closes the keyboard. That's mostly in this code:

```
public class KeyBoard {
        private WebView mAppView;
        private DroidGap mGap;

        public KeyBoard(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
        {
            mAppView = view;
            mGap = gap;
        }

        public void showKeyBoard() {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
            mgr.showSoftInput(mAppView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            ((InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(mAppView, 0); 
        }

        public void hideKeyBoard() {
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mGap.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mAppView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I use this custom Javascript-to-Java command, the keyboard always appears as Qwerty, even if the current value of the field is already numeric and it has a type=number tag.

I've tried these:
- set type=number attribute on input element.
- always have a numeric value ready (set value to zero before calling soft keyboard)
- set focus on the input (and select its value) before calling soft keyboard
- I've read solutions about setting properties of a TextView/EditText, but since my app is a browser app, the only Android object I can manipulate is the WebView.
- Setting the default input method on a Java WebView is currently not possible with Android.

The trouble with using Javascript-to-Java to open the soft keyboard is that it's a "generic" command, i.e. it's not tied specifically to the input. So the soft keyboard is opened in its default mode with no regard to the element where its keystrokes will be sent.

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi Harish, no, I went back to letting the user click the field.